# In orchard where to put my Custom UserRankingActivity code, in a widget or a plugin?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, orchardcms

I have some business logic that monitors user activity, badges, audits and ranking. I plan to show the data in a admin and public webpage, so has its own web views.

I am trying to package this into Orchard. While I understand that orchard had modular architecture, but its unclear on what the differences are, or are they the same thing? **So, my question is - how should this be packaged this as a widget or a plug-in, or does it not matter?**

What would be the different from *a) user perspective* and *b) developer perspective?* or are they the same thing?

Comment: Why the down vote without a comment? I am trying to figure out if I should put my code in the widget or the plugin?

Comment: The term 'plugin' doesn't really exist in Orchard. I think what you are referring to is a Module. Custom code to extend Orchard should go into a module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module is a bunch of code that relies on Orchard's APIs, (and possibly on the API of other modules), packaged to be easily installed. Widgets are reusable pieces of UI. They are a part of a module, so the question sounds a bit like a category error ;)

Your features have to be packaged in a module, that's the only way to extend Orchard, but what's in that module seems to be the real question here. I'd advise you read more documentation to understand the basic concepts in Orchard, and then it should naturally click into place, and you should be able to figure out what concept to use for each part of your design.

These are good places to start:

- http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Basic-Orchard-Concepts/
- http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Getting-Started-with-Modules/

Comment: Thx, I'm including 3rd party controls e.g. badges, charts, grid (compose into a shopping cart/catalog collection of purchases). Based on your answer, since its a grid packaged as shopping cart - features wise, I undrstnd it belongs in module (from a bcknd POV). But to enable frontend (display and administration) I want to let users reuse it like a wp-widget or plugin, what is needed/optional? as I code the cart, I found *concept hard to undrstand in Orchard*. Should I derive `contentpartrecord` n put my grid inside it, then attach the driver and handler to wire it up. A pic would be hlpful :)

Comment: Again, a module is a packaging vehicle. It can contain many different kinds of extensions: code, UI, you name it. I'm not sure why you want to derive from content part record. It's hard to understand what it is you're trying to do, in fact, so it's even harder to tell you how to do it.

Comment: I should probably also mention that there already are shopping carts available for Orchard. It may be a better idea for you to use one of those. If you don't want or can't do that, just looking at their code may be a good idea to get you started on how a similar and successfully implemented module would look like.

Comment: thanks I saw that, we are doing something a good deal different